# How to install Macaulay2 for Mac?

Tags: command-line, emacs

I'm trying to install Macaulay2 in Mac, Im trying to do what the [manual](https://macaulay2.com/Downloads/MacOSX/ReadMe-MacOSX.txt) says, but I'm stuck in step 4.

[image]

I write what the manual says but the terminal says function> and I don't know what to write here

Comment: Note that you can get a slightly more up-to-date installation using (if you have homebrew already) `brew install Macaulay2/tap/M2`, as described at https://macaulay2.com/Downloads/MacOSX/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the manual you linked:

```text
First change to the Macaulay2 folder (here we suppose that it is in your
Applications folder), and then run the 'setup' routine in Macaulay2:

    cd /Applications/Macaulay2-1.6
    cd bin
    ./M2
      setup()  -- this line and the next are typed inside of 
      exit     -- Macaulay2: answer the prompts which follow.

After you log out and in again, your PATH will have Macaulay2's bin directory
on it.  The 'setup' routine will modify (some of) your shell command init files
(such as .profile, .bashrc, .login, .cshrc), and your .emacs file.  The
existing files are backed up first.  It also writes a file .profile-Macaulay2
in your home directory which does the actual work including putting M2 on your
path.  Once again, a backup is created first, if the file already exists.
```

So, in Terminal, run

- `cd /Applications/Macaulay2-1.6/bin`
- `./M2` (this starts Macaulay2)
- `setup()`
- `exit`
- Restart Terminal

Comment: when I write ./M2 I get kevinduran@MacBook-Air-de-Kevin bin % ./M2
./M2: line 9: /Applications/Macaulay2-1.21/bin/M2-binary: Bad CPU type in executable
./M2: line 9: /Applications/Macaulay2-1.21/bin/M2-binary: Undefined error: 0
kevinduran@MacBook-Air-de-Kevin bin %

Comment: You get "Bad CPU Type"? what cpu do you have and what does the installer expect?

Comment: @KevinDuran What happened before the first time you ran it (screenshot in the question) and now?

Comment: @SolarMike i have a MacBook Air with chip M2

Comment: @nohillside when I write M2 after write exit and restart the console says zsh: command not found: m2

Comment: Well, given that error you say you get "Bad cpu Type" then something does not match or is not recognized.

Comment: @KevinDuran Please read the instructions carefully, the command is called `M2`, not `m2`.

Comment: @nohillside Yes im writing M2 not m2, but the terminal says that

Comment: I assume `M2` is a script which calls other stuff. But I don't have the package installed, so you might be better of raising this on https://github.com/Macaulay2/Macaulay2-web-site/issues